# How can I use custom highlighting for matched code in VS Code?

Tags: csv, syntax, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set up custom syntax highlighting (foreground and background color) for matched text.

I'm using a CSV file, example line:

"n","","","2018-12-25 06:25:36PM"

I'd like to highlight the "n" as dark green background and light green foreground. Maybe a border too?

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [highlight extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight):

In your settings:

```
"highlight.regexes": {

    "(\\\")([^\\\"]*?)(\\\",)(.*)$": {

      "regexFlags": "m",
      "filterFileRegex" : ".*\\.csv",
      "decorations" : [
        {},  // first capture group, " do nothing
        {    // the second capture group that you are interested in
         "color": "lightgreen",
         "fontWeight": "bold",
         "padding": "3px",  // only pads top and bottom unfortunately
         "backgroundColor": "darkgreen",
         "border": "1px solid white",
         "borderRadius": "3px"
        },
        {}  // third capture group, ", do nothing
      ]
    }
}
```

This will apply the highlight filter to only .csv files, you can modify that entry if your files have a different extension.

The regex assumes this pattern:

```
"n","","","2018-12-25 06:25:36PM"
```

and you want to color whatever is in the first pair of parentheses, so it could be:

```
"nabcd...more","","","2018-12-25 06:25:36PM"
```